# Float:left e float:right em resoluções menores

Tags: css

Eu tenho o componente 1 em `float:left` e o componente 2 em `float:rigth`, , porém o problema ocorre quando em resolução menores o componente 2 fica a baixo do componente 1 voltado pro lado direito e o componente um 1 voltado pro lado esquerdo.

Meu objetivo é que em resoluções menores o componente 2 ficar alinhado com o outro ao lado esquerdo.

Esclarecendo melhor o componente fica abaixo do outro, em resoluções menores um voltado pro lado esquerdo o outro pro lado direito.

Também lembrando que não posso dar `float:left` pros 2, se não vai ficar 1 abaixo do outro em resolução maiores.

Comment: Isso acontece porque um componente sobrepõe o outro. Você não ligaria para essa sobreposição? Esses componentes possuem o quê? Textos? Imagens?

Comment: O componente 1 é registro o outro é login social

Comment: É que fica incompatível com o celular um pro lado esquerdo outro pro lado direito

Comment: Seria melhor que um botão ficasse abaixo do outro mesmo, só ajustando no CSS para eles assumirem a largura da tela. Como eu disse anteriormente, há a quebra de espaço para não haver sobreposição de elementos.

Comment: Você pode utilizar o `@media` para ajustar isso.

Comment: Qual é o `margin` e o `padding` **calculado** destes elementos? São `div`s? Para ver isso use o firebug ou clica em F12 no navegador e vê quais são os valores calculados, não os setados.

Comment: @media? não só familarizado

Comment: o problema não e na margin e padding, o problema e que em resolução de celulares, um componente fica abaixo do outro um pro lado esquerdo e o outro pro lado direito, em resoluções menores ainda não da nem para notar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa questão se deve ao fato de que a soma do tamanho dos dois elementos é grande demais para caber na largura da tela, e por isso há essa quebra de espaço. Já que seu problema está na exibição em uma tela de celular, eu sugiro que você use [media queries](http://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/) para aperfeiçoar o seu sistema em relação a exibição na tela de celulares.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  background-color: green;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  background-color: red;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .right,
  .left {
    display: block;
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="left">
    Left is the left choice :D
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    Right is the right choice :3
  </div>
</div>
```